# ASP.net ListView control

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, listview

I am displaying the products catalog on my e-commerce site using ListView but how can I limit the amount of products that I want to show per page? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This web page will tell you how to setup a `DataPager` on a `ListView`. The setting on the pager for controlling the number of rows per page is `PageSize`.

- [Using ASP.NET 3.5's ListView and DataPager Controls: Paging Through Data with the ListView and DataPager Controls](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125144848/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021308-1.aspx)

Here is a snippet of code to setup a `DataPager`. Note that `PagedControlID` should be the id of your list view control. The `PageSize="50"` specifies that fifty rows per page are displayed.

```
<asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="dpMyDatePager" PageSize="50"
 PagedControlID="lvMyListView">
    <Fields>
        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True"
         ShowFirstPageButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, that was very informative and helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can put the page size by having this in layout template

```
 <asp:DataPager ID="dpListView" runat="server" PageSize="2">
```